# For Loop chunking in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested

I have some data that looks like this:

```
Trace Name             Value
Exp.618.1.1. Saline    -562
Exp.618.1.2. Ref       -30
Exp.618.1.3. 100nM     -50
Exp.618.1.4. 1uM       -65
Exp.618.1.5. 10uM      -75
Exp.619.2.1 Saline     -540
Exp.619.2.2 Ref        -463
Exp.619.2.3. 100nM     -40
Exp.619.2.4 1uM        -39
Exp.619.2.5 10uM       -37
```

I'd like to normalize this data to the Ref row. Each Exp has 5 rows and the ref always comes in the 2nd row. how can i do this with for loops? I'm thinking I need to for loops but I'm not sure how.

thanks!

Comment: Note: I need each exp to me normalized to its own Ref row, not to just the first Ref in the set.

Comment: What do you want to do? "normalize this data to the Ref row" or "average the surrounding traces to that ref trace", whatever the latter means?

Comment: ah sorry. I need to take the saline from 618.1.1 and divide it by the ref row. and do the same for the 619.1.1 trace, etc, etc.

Comment: Are there 2 or 3 columns? Please provide something like dput(head(your_data, 15)).

Comment: Yes, so you need to normalize to the ref, ok. I suggest you remove "I need to average the surrounding traces to that ref trace." which is quite confusing.

Comment: Well the row names have some sensitive names in (company secrets). but there is only 1 column of data, and the row names which look like the examples above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Trace Name             Value
                Exp.618.1.1. Saline    -562
                 Exp.618.1.2. Ref       -30
                 Exp.618.1.3. 100nM     -50
                 Exp.618.1.4. 1uM       -65
                 Exp.618.1.5. 10uM      -75
                 Exp.619.2.1 Saline     -540
                 Exp.619.2.2 Ref        -463
                 Exp.619.2.3. 100nM     -40
                 Exp.619.2.4 1uM        -39
                 Exp.619.2.5 10uM       -37", header = TRUE)
```

Package data.table is useful here (but you could also use dplyr and a number of other split-apply-combine tools).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
```

Create a column that identifies the experiment. I use `gsub` with a look behind regex for this:

```
DF[, Exp := gsub("(?<=\\d\\.[\\d+]).+", "", Trace, perl = TRUE)]
```

Adjust the regex as needed.

Then you can do your operation by experiment:

```
DF[, Value_norm := Value / Value[2], by = Exp]

#           Trace   Name Value       Exp  Value_norm
# 1: Exp.618.1.1. Saline  -562 Exp.618.1 18.73333333
# 2: Exp.618.1.2.    Ref   -30 Exp.618.1  1.00000000
# 3: Exp.618.1.3.  100nM   -50 Exp.618.1  1.66666667
# 4: Exp.618.1.4.    1uM   -65 Exp.618.1  2.16666667
# 5: Exp.618.1.5.   10uM   -75 Exp.618.1  2.50000000
# 6:  Exp.619.2.1 Saline  -540 Exp.619.2  1.16630670
# 7:  Exp.619.2.2    Ref  -463 Exp.619.2  1.00000000
# 8: Exp.619.2.3.  100nM   -40 Exp.619.2  0.08639309
# 9:  Exp.619.2.4    1uM   -39 Exp.619.2  0.08423326
#10:  Exp.619.2.5   10uM   -37 Exp.619.2  0.07991361
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you! A quick question:

in the last part, where it says Value/Value[2], is the 2 based on the position in the group or based on the 618.1.2? If the latter, how can i do based on position because the 2 is something I just made up for clarity.

Comment: It's based on position as you indicated in your question. You can of course use `Value[Name == "Ref"]` if you cannot rely on position, but will have to sacrifice some speed then. It's simple vector subsetting. You should be familiar with that.

Comment: Ah okay. thanks. That makes sense. Sorry to lay another question on you. There is only 1 column and that is Value, so when I run your code, I get some weird Exp column. In my ex above, the Trace name isn't a column, its actually the row names ( sorry if that was confusing). So when I run your code, I get something like this:

    V1         Exp
  6           c(6.-106.-81.-213.-67) 


Thanks again!

Comment: Use `setDT(DF, keep.rownames = TRUE)` and use the `rn` column instead of the `Trace` column. Btw., you are supposed to share a minimal, reproducible, *representative* example.

Comment: Thank you. works perfectly. Will try to give better examples next time!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(exptid = substr(dat$Trace, 1, 9)) %>%
        mutate(normalised = Value / Value[Name == "Ref"])

Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
Groups: exptid [2]

          Trace   Name Value    exptid  normalised
         (fctr) (fctr) (int)     (chr)       (dbl)
1  Exp.618.1.1. Saline  -562 Exp.618.1 18.73333333
2  Exp.618.1.2.    Ref   -30 Exp.618.1  1.00000000
3  Exp.618.1.3.  100nM   -50 Exp.618.1  1.66666667
4  Exp.618.1.4.    1uM   -65 Exp.618.1  2.16666667
5  Exp.618.1.5.   10uM   -75 Exp.618.1  2.50000000
6   Exp.619.2.1 Saline  -540 Exp.619.2  1.16630670
7   Exp.619.2.2    Ref  -463 Exp.619.2  1.00000000
8  Exp.619.2.3.  100nM   -40 Exp.619.2  0.08639309
9   Exp.619.2.4    1uM   -39 Exp.619.2  0.08423326
10  Exp.619.2.5   10uM   -37 Exp.619.2  0.07991361
```